# php stdClass access

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I have an output like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetMatchdataByLeagueDateTimeResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Matchdata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [teamId] => 40
```

Within a foreach loop

```
foreach ($allMatches as $match):
```

I woul like now to work with the data like follows:

```
if ($match->idTeam1 == $teamId || $match->idTeam2 == $teamId):
```

But I get this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Reason is, that the Matchdata Array contains about 60+ entries and I want to filter those out where the `[idTeam1]` or `[idTeam2]` == a given id.

As result I should get only about 5 to 7 entries.

What is the best way to get this done when working with stdClass Object?

Please help!

Thanks!!

Comment: Where are `idTeam1` and `idTeam2` declared? What's your object structure?

Comment: Your output example (assuming it's $allMatches?) doesn't match your pseudocode.  teamId vs idTeam1 - where is idTeam1 coming from?

Comment: does `$match[0]->idTeam1` work?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it seems like you need to be testing the variable type with the `gettype()` PHP function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: …is there a reason you're using an object versus an associative array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$response` is the structure you posted:

```
$teamId = 99; // target teamId

foreach($response->GetMatchdataByLeagueDateTimeResult->MatchData as $match)
{
    if ($match->idTeam1 == $teamId || $match->idTeam2 == $teamId)
    {
        // this `$match` has the target $teamId - do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was simple blind:
foreach ($allMatches->GetMatchdataByLeagueDateTimeResult->Matchdata as $id => $match):
    debug($id); 
    debug($match->idTeam1);

now this works: if ($match->idTeam1 == $teamId || $match->idTeam2 == $teamId) ...

Many thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Your outer structure is an object, therefore you are perhaps iterating through the visible properties of the object (see this page). If you want to iterate through the array within the object instance, you should pass it to your foreach loop, or have your class implement the Iterator interface and have its methods redirect to the array.

```
 <?php
       foreach ($object->allMatches as $match) {
              /* Your iterate body here */
       }
```